# To compare selenium xpath values

Tags: xpath

You are trying to run xpath values by comparing them.
You want to compare whether there are comments or not.

```html
<div class="media-body">
   <a href="https://url" class="ellipsis">
         <span class="pull-right count orangered">
      &nbsp;+26     </span>
            post title   </a>
   <div class="media-info ellipsis">
    admin    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> date   </div>
  </div>
```

If there is a comment, span class="full-right count or changed" is generated. If you don't have it, it won't be produced.

`xpath comment //*[@id="thema_wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a/span`

xpath nocomment //*[@id="thema_wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a/

I think we can compare this with if,else,but I don't know how.

`if
  #nocomment start
else
  #comment stop`

I searched a lot for the data, but I couldn't find it. Please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are even trying to do. That xpath looks horrible. I recommend locating the elements with classnames or something more readable than direct xpath. You can test if element contains text with //*[contains(text(),'your text')]

Comment: I don't click on posts with comments on Selenium.
I want to make a program that clicks on posts without comments.
What other ways are there without using xpath? I'm still studying, so I'm not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XPath example to select/click on something  without comment. This website seems to use the same system as your sample data :

http://cineaste.co.kr/

To select the entries with no comment for the movies block ("영화이야기"), just use :

```
//h3[.="영화이야기"]/following::div[@class="widget-small-box"][1]//li[@class="ellipsis"][not(contains(.,"+"))]
```

We verify the presence of the "+" in the li node to filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's the same system. I tested it and there was an error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[.='영화이야기']/following::div[@class='widget-small-box'][1]//li[@class='ellipsis'][not(contains(.,'+'))]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path = "C:\chromed\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path) #path
'''

'''
driver.get("http://cineaste.co.kr/") #url
time.sleep(0.5)

postclick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[.='영화이야기']/following::div[@class='widget-small-box'][1]//li[@class='ellipsis'][not(contains(.,'+'))]") #로그인창 활성화
postclick.click()


driver.close()
```

Could you make an example with the site? I want to ignore the posts with comments and just click the ones without comments.